# A book of quotations using epigraphs qitems - page wrapping

Tags: wrap, page, epigraphs

I am producing a book of quotations and have begun using the epigraphs package.

I am using one qitem per quotation and have around 100 quotations in total.

The issue I am facing is that the qitems are not page wrapping. I achieve the first four or five quotations on the page and then everything else is cut off.

Is there a way to instruct natural page wrapping of the qitems automatically? Ideally I would like to keep each qitem together on the same page if possible.

```
\begin{epigraphs}

\qitem{\itshape ``This is my first inspiration quote for the book''}{\textit{---John Smith}}

\vspace{10mm} %10mm vertical space

\qitem{\itshape ``And here is another quotation''}{\textit{---Jane Doe}}

\vspace{10mm} %10mm vertical space

\qitem{\itshape ``And yet another''}{\textit{---William Jones}}

\end{epigraphs}
```

Comment: Welcome. Instead oft just posting a code snippet, its better to provide a compilable Minimal Working Example. Thus, other user can easy debbug your problem.